# Convert numbers (index values) to Alphabet values with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert the id's of an dataframe into an alphabetical list based on the index value.

Then I need to apply that "alpha" value to another dataframe with the data that will be listed.

so instead of this data showing the client id number:

```
2011-05-13  #483 ....
2011-05-13  #483 .... 
2011-05-13  #553 ....
2011-05-13  #555 ....
```

with this index of the list:

```
#483 - Client 1 
#551 - Client 2
#553 - Client 3
#554 - Client 4
#555 - Client 5
```

So I want the data output to be something like this:

```
2011-05-13  #A  ....
2011-05-13  #A  ....
2011-05-13  #C  ....
2011-05-13  #D  ....
```

Index becomes:

```
#A - Client 1 
#B - Client 2
#C - Client 3
#D - Client 4
#F - Client 5
```

I am using Pandas and this is the client dataframe.  Can I create the alpha list based on the index?

df_accts

```
    id   client        
0  483  Client 1    
1  551  Client 2     
2  553  Client 3   
3  554  Client 4     
4  555  Client 5
```

There will be between 1 ad 15 clients per report so no need to worry about things like AA or BB.

thank so much.

Comment: Do you have no more than 26 rows?

Comment: No.  That would be a freak event if there was.

Comment: Please add this limitation to the question because it makes your expected solution possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a dictionary that maps clients to letters:

```
import string
d = dict(zip(df_acts['client'].unique(), string.ascii_uppercase))
```

Then, replace the clients with the corresponding letters here and in any other dataframe:

```
df_acts['client'] = df_acts['client'].replace(d)
#    id client
#0  483      A
#1  551      B
#2  553      C
#3  554      D
#4  555      E
```